# Looking for alternative PHP fgetcsv() function to handlle textfiles

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a web interface to enable a user import data from text files into mysql database.

I am wondering if anyone knows whether there is another function to handle text files as what I have seen so far is the fgetcsv() for handling csv file. One other way could be to convert the text files into csv file which I do not want. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: Ok, your file is now a .txt but what format do your new file have ? I mean, what is inside the .txt ? Each line with a mysql row ? data separated by something ? each txt will be different. Please, be more specific.

Comment: @Deceze, it has been my thinking that the fgetcsv() would be strictly for .csv files hence my wish to ask for another function to handle .txt files which am working with. @Chouchenous, the data in the text files am working with are comma delimited and they are not mysql rows. After removing some errors which I thought had to do with the accepted file extension for the function, I ran the script using the fgetcsv() for the .txt file and it worked. This means the use of fgetcsv is not strict or what? What is the essence of the csv that is attached to the function name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `fgetcsv()` with `fgets()`, which gets a line from the file pointer rather than a CSV "line".

Comment: Thanks Pelle, I would try to use that and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

> This means the use of fgetcsv is not strict or what? What is the essence of the csv that is attached to the function name?

CSV means "[comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)". All it means is that there's a line of text which has commas in it, the commas separating values. E.g:

```
Value 1,Value 2,Value 3
```

That's pretty much all there is to it. This is a more or less standardized way of saving flat arrays or *rows of data* in a language neutral way. <sub>(There are some details about, e.g., saving values that themselves have commas in them, but that's the gist of it. Functions like `fgetcsv` exist to take care of these details without you having to reinvent the wheel every time.)</sub>
The PHP-native equivalent to the above would be `array('Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3')`.

All `fgetcsv` does is read a line at a time from a file, find the commas in it and give you back an array of the data it found. It does this for any file you tell it to read, it doesn't care the least bit about the file extension. If there are no commas in the line it doesn't do very much and only gives you a single value back. The CSV format itself is so simple there's not even a real standard for it, so there's nothing `fgetcsv` could be "strict" about very much.